# Filtering by an ISNULL statement within SELECT statement

Tags: sql, isnull

I'm stuck on a portion of code where I can not figure out how to use ISNULL correctly.
I'm trying to find all sales prices for an item by location and by variant code.  The issue is that not all items with variants are priced in the sales price table at the variant level.  I'm trying to say if there is no variant match, find where variant = ''.

```
SELECT  [Item Ledger].[Location Code], [Item Ledger].[Item No_] AS "No_", [Item Ledger].[Variant Code]
, (SELECT   [Item].[Description] FROM   [Wings$Item] AS "Item"  WHERE   [Item].[No_] = [Item Ledger].[Item No_]) AS "Description"
, (SELECT   [Item Variant].[Variant Dimension 1] FROM [Wings$Item Variant Registration] AS "Item Variant" WHERE [Item Variant].[Item No_] = [Item Ledger].[Item No_] 
    AND [Item Variant].[Variant] = [Item Ledger].[Variant Code]) AS "Color"
, (SELECT   [Item Variant].[Variant Dimension 2] FROM [Wings$Item Variant Registration] AS "Item Variant" WHERE [Item Variant].[Item No_] = [Item Ledger].[Item No_] 
    AND [Item Variant].[Variant] = [Item Ledger].[Variant Code]) AS "Size"
, (SELECT   [Item].[Vendor No_] FROM    [Wings$Item] AS "Item"  WHERE   [Item].[No_] = [Item Ledger].[Item No_]) AS "Vendor No."
, (SELECT   [Item].[Division Code] FROM [Wings$Item] AS "Item"  WHERE   [Item].[No_] = [Item Ledger].[Item No_]) AS "Division Code"
, (SELECT   [Item].[Item Category Code] FROM    [Wings$Item] AS "Item"  WHERE   [Item].[No_] = [Item Ledger].[Item No_]) AS "Item Category Code"
, (SELECT   [Item Category].[Description] FROM [Wings$Item Category] AS "Item Category" WHERE [Item Category].[Code] = [Item Ledger].[Item Category Code]) AS "Item Cat. Description"
, (SELECT   [Item].[Product Group Code] FROM    [Wings$Item] AS "Item"  WHERE   [Item].[No_] = [Item Ledger].[Item No_]) AS "Product Group Code"
, (SELECT   [Product Group].[Description] FROM [Wings$Product Group] AS "Product Group" WHERE [Product Group].[Code] = [Item Ledger].[Product Group Code]) AS "Prod. Group Description"
, (SELECT   CAST([Item].[Last Direct Cost] AS decimal(18,2)) FROM   [Wings$Item] AS "Item"  WHERE   [Item].[No_] = [Item Ledger].[Item No_]) AS "Last Cost"

, (SELECT DISTINCT  CAST(MAX([Sales Price].[Unit Price]) as decimal(18,2))
    FROM [Wings$Sales Price] AS "Sales Price", [Wings$Store Price Group] AS "Store Price"
    WHERE EXISTS 
        (SELECT DISTINCT  [Store Price].[Store]
            , [Sales Price].[Item No_]
            , (SELECT   [Item].[Description] FROM [Wings$Item] AS "Item" WHERE [Item].[No_] = [Sales Price].[Item No_]) AS "Description"
            , [Sales Price].[Variant Code]
            , [Sales Price].[Sales Code]
            , CAST([Sales Price].[Unit Price] as decimal(18,2)) AS "Unit Price"
        FROM [Wings$Sales Price] AS "Sales Price" JOIN [Wings$Picking _ Receiving lines] AS "Picking Lines" ON [Sales Price].[Item No_] = [Picking Lines].[Item No_] 
            JOIN [Wings$Store Price Group] AS "Store Price" ON [Store Price].[Price Group Code] = [Sales Price].[Sales Code] 
            AND [Store Price].[Store] = [Picking Lines].[Shortcut Dimension 1 Code] WHERE [Sales Price].[Starting Date] > [Sales Price].[Ending Date])
            AND [Store Price].[Store] = [Item Ledger].[Location Code] AND [Sales Price].[Item No_] = [Item Ledger].[Item No_] 
            AND [Sales Price].[Variant Code] = [Item Ledger].[Variant Code] AND [Store Price].[Price Group Code] = [Sales Price].[Sales Code]) AS "Retail Price"


, (SELECT   MIN([Purch Rec].[Posting Date]) FROM [Wings$Purch_ Rcpt_ Line] AS "Purch Rec" WHERE [Purch Rec].[No_] = [Item Ledger].[Item No_] AND [Purch Rec].[Variant Code] = [Item Ledger].[Variant Code]) 
    AS "First Rec Date"
, (SELECT   MAX([Purch Rec].[Posting Date]) FROM [Wings$Purch_ Rcpt_ Line] AS "Purch Rec" WHERE [Purch Rec].[No_] = [Item Ledger].[Item No_] AND [Purch Rec].[Variant Code] = [Item Ledger].[Variant Code]) 
    AS "Last Rec Date"
, (SELECT   MAX([Sales Line].[Date]) FROM [Wings$Trans_ Sales Entry] AS "Sales Line" WHERE [Sales Line].[Item No_] = [Item Ledger].[Item No_] AND [Sales Line].[Variant Code] = [Item Ledger].[Variant Code]
    AND [Sales Line].[Store No_] = [Item Ledger].[Location Code]) AS "Last Sold Date"
, (SELECT   CAST(SUM([Value Entry].[Item Ledger Entry Quantity]) AS decimal(18,0)) FROM [Wings$Value Entry] AS "Value Entry" WHERE [Value Entry].[Item No_] = [Item Ledger].[Item No_]
    AND [Value Entry].[Variant Code] = [Item Ledger].[Variant Code] AND [Value Entry].[Location Code] = [Item Ledger].[Location Code] AND [Value Entry].[Posting Date] <= '20161201') AS "Beg. Balance"
, (SELECT   CAST(SUM([Transfer Shipment].[Quantity]) AS decimal(18,0)) FROM [Wings$Transfer Shipment Line] AS "Transfer Shipment" WHERE [Transfer Shipment].[Item No_] = [Item Ledger].[Item No_]
    AND [Transfer Shipment].[Variant Code] = [Item Ledger].[Variant Code] AND [Transfer Shipment].[Transfer-from Code] = [Item Ledger].[Location Code]) AS "Outbound Transfers"
, (SELECT   CAST(SUM([Transfer Receipt].[Quantity]) AS decimal(18,0)) FROM [Wings$Transfer Receipt Line] AS "Transfer Receipt" WHERE [Transfer Receipt].[Item No_] = [Item Ledger].[Item No_]
    AND [Transfer Receipt].[Variant Code] = [Item Ledger].[Variant Code] AND [Transfer Receipt].[Transfer-to Code] = [Item Ledger].[Location Code]) AS "Inbound Transfers"
, (SELECT   CAST(SUM([Purch. Rec.].[Quantity]) AS decimal(18,0)) FROM [Wings$Purch_ Rcpt_ Line] AS "Purch. Rec." WHERE [Purch. Rec.].[No_] = [Item Ledger].[Item No_]
    AND [Purch. Rec.].[Variant Code] = [Item Ledger].[Variant Code] AND [Purch. Rec.].[Location Code] = [Item Ledger].[Location Code]) AS "YTD Purchase Receipts"
, (SELECT   CAST(SUM([Transaction Register].[Quantity]) as decimal(18,0)) FROM [Wings$Trans_ Sales Entry] AS "Transaction Register" 
    WHERE [Item Ledger].[Item No_] = [Transaction Register].[Item No_] AND [Item Ledger].[Variant Code] = [Transaction Register].[Variant Code] 
    AND [Item Ledger].[Location Code] = [Transaction Register].[Store No_]) AS "YTD Sales"  
, (SELECT   CAST(SUM([Transaction Register].[Quantity]) as decimal(18,0)) FROM [Wings$Trans_ Sales Entry] AS "Transaction Register" 
    WHERE [Item Ledger].[Item No_] = [Transaction Register].[Item No_] AND [Item Ledger].[Variant Code] = [Transaction Register].[Variant Code] 
    AND [Item Ledger].[Location Code] = [Transaction Register].[Store No_] AND [Transaction Register].[Date] >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) -1, 0) 
    AND [Transaction Register].[Date] < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) , 0)) AS "Last Month Sales"
, (SELECT   CAST(SUM([Transaction Register].[Quantity]) as decimal(18,0)) FROM [Wings$Trans_ Sales Entry] AS "Transaction Register" 
    WHERE [Item Ledger].[Item No_] = [Transaction Register].[Item No_] AND [Item Ledger].[Variant Code] = [Transaction Register].[Variant Code] 
    AND [Item Ledger].[Location Code] = [Transaction Register].[Store No_] AND [Transaction Register].[Date] >= DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE()) 
    AND [Transaction Register].[Date] < EOMONTH(GETDATE())) AS "Current Month Sales"
, (SELECT   CAST(SUM([Transfer Line].[Outstanding Quantity]) AS decimal(18,0)) FROM [Wings$Transfer Line] AS "Transfer Line" WHERE [Transfer Line].[Item No_] = [Item Ledger].[Item No_]
    AND [Transfer Line].[Variant Code] = [Item Ledger].[Variant Code] AND [Transfer Line].[Transfer-to Code] = [Item Ledger].[Location Code]) AS "Current In-Transit to Store"
, (SELECT   CAST(SUM([Item Ledger].[Quantity]) as decimal(18,0))) AS "Current on Hand"
, (SELECT   CAST(SUM([Value Entry].[Item Ledger Entry Quantity]) as decimal(18,0)) FROM [Wings$Value Entry] AS "Value Entry" WHERE [Value Entry].[Item No_] = [Item Ledger].[Item No_]
    AND [Value Entry].[Variant Code] = [Item Ledger].[Variant Code] AND [Value Entry].[Location Code] = [Item Ledger].[Location Code] AND [Value Entry].[Location Code] LIKE '9%') AS "Whse Inv."
, (SELECT   CAST(SUM([Value Entry].[Item Ledger Entry Quantity]) as decimal(18,0)) FROM [Wings$Value Entry] AS "Value Entry" WHERE [Value Entry].[Item No_] = [Item Ledger].[Item No_]
    AND [Value Entry].[Variant Code] = [Item Ledger].[Variant Code] AND [Value Entry].[Location Code] = [Item Ledger].[Location Code] AND [Value Entry].[Location Code] NOT LIKE '9%') AS "Store Inv."
, (SELECT   CAST(SUM([Purchase Line].[Outstanding Quantity]) as decimal(18,0)) FROM [Wings$Purchase Line] AS "Purchase Line" WHERE  [Item Ledger].[Item No_] = [Purchase Line].[No_] 
    AND [Purchase Line].[Location Code] = [Item Ledger].[Location Code] AND [Purchase Line].[Variant Code] = [Item Ledger].[Variant Code]) AS "Qty. on PO"
FROM    [Wings$Item Ledger Entry] AS "Item Ledger", [Wings$Store Price Group] AS "Store Price" WHERE [Item Ledger].[Location Code] = [Store Price].[Store] AND [Item Ledger].[Location Code] = [Store Price].[Store]
GROUP BY    [Item Ledger].[Location Code], [Item Ledger].[Item No_], [Item Ledger].[Variant Code], [Item Ledger].[Item Category Code], [Item Ledger].[Product Group Code], [Store Price].[Price Group Code], [Store Price].[Store]
```

Comment: Try to reproduce the odd behavior with minimal code -- the smallest select statement that produces the effect you want help with.

Comment: @joeCast Your code i snot properly formatted. Provide a simple version of your query to clearly show what you are asking for. That aside; null values cannot be compared and a comparison of a null is ALWAYS false. ISNULL(MyColumn, 'Some replacement val') will provide a replacement value that can be used in your criteria. Consider the following true statement when the col is null:  ISNULL(MyCol, 'foo') = 'foo'

Comment: Figured it out by doing a RIGHTJOIN to the different tables within multiple ISNULL statements.  Thanks for your help!